# Jmeter adds extra characters ï»¿ when reading from a csv

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm reading some values from a csv like this:

[image]

But I'm getting some strange extra characters at the beginning of the ID value like this:
[image]

The CSV file is just an id, a name and line breaks.  Why do I get these other characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific characters you see (`ï»¿` or `EF BB BF` in hex) are [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-8. So it is coming from your CSV file, likely somehow added on saving the file. So try to set **File encoding** parameter to `UTF-8`, it should help.

Comment: It helps, but now is showing a question mark (?) before the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have selected UTF-8 as encoding, It worked fine for few parameters, but I still observed **ï»¿** before one parameter i.e URL.

CSV used: url,id,token

- Url looks like: abc.def.ghi.jkl.com
- Id looks like: jhas880ad
- token is JWT token

I observed following exception in jMeter response:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ?abc.def.ghi.jkl.com
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at
```

Then after a long research, following solution worked for me:

1. Jmeter put ï»¿ as prefix for the value of 1st variable taken from CSV file
2. Thus I used one dummy entry in beginning of csv file and wrote dummy variable name in jMeter csv data set config
   [click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVkos.png)

Updated CSV looked like: dummy,url,id,token

This solution might not be practical for huge data but if you have very few records then you can consider this.

Also, if someone is aware of another workaround, feel free to post.

Answer (score -1):

If you are exporting a ResultSet from DBeaver to a CSV, once you get to the "Output" tab, make sure to select "UTF-8" in the "Encoding" list AND to uncheck the "Insert BOM" box.  That worked for me.